# Rmarkdown report from params chosen by user in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm trying to build an Rmarkdown report with a params argument which takes a list of various outputs (plots, tables and other objects chosen from a shiny app). The problem i'm having is showing all the outputs in the list with in a markdown report.

If we have a list of outputs:

```
outputs = list("A" = "Output...", "B" = summary(rnorm(100)), "C" = 111)
```

The desired output can be obtained by:

````
---
title: "Report"
output: html_document
params:
  output: NA
---

```{echo = F}
outputs.list = params$output
outputs.list[[1]]
outputs.list[[2]]
outputs.list[[3]]
```
````

and rendering with the outputs: `render("report.rmd", params = list(output = outputs))`.

However the length of output is unknown, how can I make the rmarkdown template dynamic to the length of the outputs list.

Comment: Why don’t you just `print` the list?

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
print(outputs.list)
```

Thanks @divibisan, I thought I had tried this but it is working now.